# Expand background from center (CSS / Javascript)

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

Please note the example below has music play automatically! If you wish to mute your speakers, please do so before accessing the example.

I'm recreating [this site](http://nordicacondos.com/) which was originally done in flash. Basically on the flash site, there are 5 main buttons, 'Discover', 'Experience', 'Reside', 'Interact', and 'Connect'. When you hover these buttons, the background changes slightly as the bottom border expands out from the center.

I wouldn't mind setting the background as an image or using a border to indicate the color. Based on what I'm doing here, I imagine setting the background image for the hover effect and the normal state is easiest. I'd like for the background image to transition into the new one on hover but to have it expand from the center rather than left to right, or right to left.

Is this something I can do via CSS Transitions or jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can do it with CSS3 Transitions and/or jQuery.

Comment: Hey Chad!

Would you mind providing an example or a site that shows how I can expand it from the center with CSS Transitions?

Comment: A sound warning would have been nice! Hot tip: get rid of it unless you want everyone abandoning the site when accessing it during work hours.

Comment: What have you tried so far Brian? Show us some code to start with, rarely do I write things from scratch on this site.

Comment: Hey there. I'm so sorry -- I just added the warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS transitions you can do this quite nicely.

You could use HTML as follows

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="greyline">
        <span class="redline"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and the following CSS would animate the red line when you hover over the container box

```
.container {height:100px;width:200px;background:#eee;position:relative;}
.container span {display:block;}
.greyline {background:#ccc;height:10px;width:200px;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
.redline {background:red;height:10px;width:0;margin:auto;}
.container:hover .redline {
    width:200px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Try it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/SNzgs/1/

Browser support should be as follows: Chrome 1.0, Safari 3.2, Firefox 4.0, IE 10, Opera 10.5