# CSS3 (or jQuery) Background Color Animation Vertically from Center of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an effect like the right nav on this site:

http://dianabobar.com/

With jQuery. The way the color opens up from the middle is the effect I'm going for but unfortunately that site is done in Flash so I don't have the option of studying how it's done. I'm not really sure what to search for. I was thinking something like 'background radial animation jquery' or 'background color animation from center jquery.'

I also considered a CSS3 ease-in like they've detailed here ([Expand background from center (CSS / Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147319/expand-background-from-center-css-javascript)). The problem is that the answer on this question is only showing the CSS3 transition working horizontal when I'll need it to work vertically. I've worked with the JSFiddle that they were using on the answer (http://jsfiddle.net/SNzgs/) but I can only seem to get the transition to animate going down from the top and not out from the center. The code they have is:

```
.redline {background:red;height:10px;width:0;margin:auto;}

.container:hover .redline {
    width:200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

The code I tried was:

```
.redline {background:red;height:0px;width:10px;margin:auto;}

.container:hover .redline {
    height:200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with `:after` pseudo element and absolute positioning. Then you can combine `height` and `top` properties of that *shading box*.
I made a completely new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SNzgs/5/ since yours was built to do the job horizontaly.

```
.container:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    top: 0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;

    transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.container:hover:after {
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Woah, great minds think alike! I think your solution is more elegant than mine though - yours rely on a single pseudo element, but I was a little silly and used both instead ;) +1

Comment: Thank you very much. My fiddle isn't such rich and neat as yours though. +1 for you too.

Comment: Everybody had great answers, I chose you. Thanks! A great solution (and thanks everyone else too +1!)

Comment: I appreciate very much.

Answer (score 3):

My solution is similar to that of by matewka, but uses both `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. The example markup is as follow:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

For the CSS:

```
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 6em;
}
nav ul li {
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul li:before,
    nav ul li:after {
        background-color: #333;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        top: 50%;       /* Vertically positions pseudo elements in the center */
        bottom: 50%;    /* Vertically positions pseudo elements in the center */
        transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
        z-index: 50;
    }
nav ul li a {
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    transition: all .125s ease-in-out;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #eee;
}
    nav ul li:hover:before {
        top: 0;    /* Forces :before to stretch to fill top half */
    }
    nav ul li:hover:after {
        bottom: 0; /* Forces :after to stretch to fill bottom half */
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/rRtmB/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:after` pseudo element to create the animating background:

**CSS**

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
ul > li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
ul > li:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #353535;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms;
    transition: all 400ms;
}
ul > li:hover:after {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/83Bce/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

This works (though I'm not sure this is exactly what you want):

```
.container {height:100px;width:200px;background:#eee;position:relative;}
.container span {display:block;}
.greyline {background:#ccc;height:10px;width:200px;position:absolute;bottom:0;}
.redline {background:red;height:0;width:200px;margin:auto; top:5px;position:relative;}
.container:hover .redline {
    height:10px;
    top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: FYI, centering elements vertically in CSS tends to be harder than horizontally, so you need to specify more things...

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate a similar effect with few modifications at your fiddle:

```
<div class="container">
    <span class="vertgrey">
        <span class="vertredline"></span>        
    </span>
    <span class="greyline">
        <span class="redline"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {height:100px;width:200px;background:#eee;position:relative;}
.container span {display:block;}
.greyline {background:#ccc;height:10px;width:200px;position:absolute;bottom:45px;}
.redline, .vertredline {background:red;height:10px;width:0;margin:auto;}
.vertgrey {
    background: #CCC;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    left: 90px;
}
.container:hover .redline {
    width:200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.container:hover .vertredline {
    height:100%;
    width: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

This is the link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SNzgs/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here's my shot at a solution for you:

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/gF28Y/

css:

```
.container {height:100px;width:200px;background:#eee;position:absolute;}
.greyline {display:block;position:relative;background:#000;height:0%;width:100%;}
.redline {display:block;position:relative;background:#f00;height:0%;width:100%;margin-top:50px;}
.container:hover .redline {
    margin-top:0px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="greyline">
       <div class="redline"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```